# Flash card web app that works with mobile browsers

Tags: webapp-rec, mobile

A long time ago (1999), I had a mobile app called [Flash!](http://software.smartphonereviews.us/palm,c3ltYmlhbjgzMjM,flash.html) for Palm OS that I could use to enter multi-line questions and multi-line answers into and then later study them with multiple choice or just flipping the flash card around.

[image: This is what Flash! Looked Like]

I'm looking for a similar web app that's compatible with modern mobile browsers (particularly Opera Mini) with these features:

- PDA/phone finger friendly question/answer navigation (using that little 4 way button on the bottom of the PDA)
- Multi-line questions and answers.
- Multiple choice quizzes (which selects answers from other questions at random).
- Non-multiple choice quizzes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [AnkiWeb](http://ankiweb.net), the online version of the popular [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) flashcards app.

The simple HTML design makes it reliable and easy to use on tiny devices.

In addition to the webapp, you might want to use Linux/Windows/Mac/Android/iPhone applications and their synchronization features.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using HeadMagnet
http://www.headmagnet.com/

It is free (altough there is a Pro Version) and works in my mobile explorer, which also happens to be Opera Mini (I have a QWERTY mobile -Nokia C3-). I have not explored all the functionalities, so maybe there is a feature for multiple choice quizzes

Answer (score 0):

I'm very familiar with your problem.  I used to use [Supermemo](http://www.supermemo.com/) on my Palm device.

Try:

1. For flashcards that sit in the cloud - the [Flashcard module](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Flashcard_module) in [Moodle](http://moodle.com/hosting/).
2. For flashcards on your device - [MiniPauker](http://pauker.sourceforge.net/pauker.php?page=home&lang=en&project=minipauker)

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of looking for an intuitive flashcard app so I built my own at [SwipeStudy.com](http://swipestudy.com) its a web-app so you just point your browser to the site whether you're on a phone or PC and study away!

Answer (score -1):

I've used [GFlash](http://www.gwhizmobile.com/Desktop/gFlash.php) in the past and been happy with it. You can create the questions in a simple Google Doc spreadsheet

Comment: Dude that's for the ipad, iphone, android, blackberry it doesn't fit within the specifications.

Comment: My bad. I thought it worked on any web browser