# Spaced repetition application

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a good web based [spaced repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) application. It should be as generic as possible, and not focused solely on language learning. Currently I use [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/), which has a web interface, but it lacks most of the features available in the desktop version.

Any suggestions?

PS. An Android client or at least a UI designed with mobile browsers in mind would be a plus.

Answer (score 0):

[FlashCardDB](http://flashcarddb.com/) allows you to browse existing sets of flashcards or create your own custom set of flashcards. It also allows you to use two learning methods:

- Leitner
- Graded Space Repetition

The Leitner System works by flashing the flashcards that a student always forgets more often.

[image]

The Graded Space Repetition Method works in a similar manner to the Leitner System but the student inputs his confidence level on his answer. Sort of a weighted answer.

[image]

You might want to give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Many such applications exist and your requirement of it being "good" sounds a bit vague so only a general answer can be given.

You might want to check out the Wikipedia entry on [List of Flashcard Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flashcard_software).

Also answers to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/flash-card-webapp-that-works-with-mobile-browsers) contain some interesting examples.

I, for one, would like to draw your attention to [Memjogger](http://memjogger.com) - it's a web based spaced repetition app build with simplicity and speed in mind (it's a [single page web app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), i.e. it uses javascript heavly to make it feel as close to a native app as possible - there are no page reloads). It supports LaTeX and exposes an API through the HTTP.

Full disclaimer: I'm the author (and the user) of Memjogger and the app is not free (but comes with a free trial).